# Is $v_{wave}=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$ valid even if wave pulse is accelerating?

Tags: waves

Consider a rope where linear mass density varies continuously , would the above formula be still valid since the pulse will be accelerating?

I have seen the derivation of above formula as given here [Wave speed derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256280/wave-speed-derivation) but in my case , in the elemental part of string chosen , we will have to include the pseudo force because the frame of reference in which pulse is at rest will be an accelerating frame.

How can we describe the wave velocity in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This formula will only be an approximation. You will have to solve the actual wave equation
$$
T\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}- \mu(x)\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=0
$$
for your given $\mu(x)$ to find out how the wave will move. These is no universal exact solution that works  for all $\mu(x)$, only approximations.